# FaceBook認証の際に、公式アプリを介して認証したい

Tags: monaca, facebook, facebook-graph-api

こんにちは。

現在Monacaのハイブリッドアプリ開発をしている者です。
FBログイン機能で躓いたので、質問させて下さい。

FaceBook認証を行う場合、FaceBook公式アプリを介して
認証したいのですが、それは実現可能でしょうか？

今の所アプリが立ち上がらず、以下のような画面が出ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この画面でログイン情報を入力すれば、確かにトークン等の取得ができます。
しかし、既にアプリを立ち上げてログインしている状態で、再度入力を
させるのは、ユーザビリティ的によろしくないのでなくしたいと考えています。

やりたい事としては、下記の質問と正反対の事を実現したいです。↓
[AndroidアプリでFacebookのログイン認証を公式アプリに行わせない方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5152/android%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%81%A7facebook%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E8%AA%8D%E8%A8%BC%E3%82%92%E5%85%AC%E5%BC%8F%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95?rq=1)

openFBというライブラリを使用する方法と、サーバにphpファイルを置いて
認証させる方法の二通りを試しましたが、どちらも同じ結果になりました。
何かご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、些細な事でも良いので
教えて頂けると助かります。

Comment: こちらのコメント欄に記述しておきました。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/35335/19445

Comment: @user19445 是非こちらの質問への回答として投稿してください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コメント欄にこちらの質問の回答として投稿した方がいいというコメントがあったので、こちらでも回答しておきます。

MonacaのようなCordovaを使うハイブリッドアプリは基本的にJavascriptによって動きを実現させているので、Webアプリと同じような挙動になります。
それと違ってLineなどのアプリはネイティブの言語を使ってアプリを作成しています。なのでFacebookが用意して‌​いるネイティブ言語用のSDKを使うことに‌​よって、この質問の動作を実現させています。

ハイブ‌​リッドアプリでネイティブ言語用のSDKを‌​使うにはこちらのプラグイン https://npmjs.com/package/aerogear-cordova-oauth2 を利用する必要がありますが、MonacaではMonaca指定のプラグイン以外を使うのは有料プランに移行する必要があります‌​。

Comment: 改めて、ご回答ありがとうございます。似たような質問をしてしまって申し訳ありません。おかげ様で開発を再開することができました。重ねてお礼申し上げます。